# ci_merchant paypal purchase it works but the money does not get to paypal account

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant

ci_merchant paypal purchase it works but the money does not get to paypal account

```
      $this->load->library('merchant');
      $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');

      $settings = array(
    'username' => '***************************',
    'password' => '****************************',
    'signature' => '***************************',
    'test_mode' => true);

  $this->merchant->initialize($settings);



     $params = array(
               'amount' => 100.00,
                'currency' => 'USD',
                 'return_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/freejoboard/index.php/empregos/payed',
                 'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/freejoboard/index.php/empregos/canceled');

          $response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
```

the paypal opens and i enter the credit card number everything works when i pay redirects to payed  webpage but the money never gets to the merchant test account

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your credentials are correct, and you are pointing to the correct environment based on the credentials that you are using.  If you can provide the email address of the account that it should of went to, the email address of the account that was making the payment and the transaction ID that you get back I can check to see what is happening with this transaction on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the purchase_return() method to confirm the payment after you have recorded it in your database.